# How to use HealthChecksUI on WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf

I'd like to know if is there some way how to add HealthChecks NuGet to WCF service cause in WCF service is not Startup.cs file, where I could configure this service. I know that WCF service is "one big Startup.cs" but can't figure out how does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF at present is not implemented in `Dotnet Core Framework`. Therefore that class library is not supported in WCF. Besides, a WCF project usually is hosted in `IIS`, namely, it is a web host. The life cycle events could be used in `ServicehostFacotory` extension.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/extending-hosting-using-servicehostfactory
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

We have to make some json, which HealthChecksUI read on andress
In my case its on localhost.../Service/json/HealthCheck

and checking only database... but you can add some code for testing another parts of service

You have to use Newtonsoft json library

So I've made it like this:

IService:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/HealthCheck", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Stream HealthCheck();
```

Service.svc.cs:

```
public Stream HealthCheck()
{
    var healthChecker = new HealthChecker();
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType ="application/json; 
    charset=utf-8";
    return new 
    MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(healthChecker.HealthStatus().ToString()));
}
```

HealthChecker.cs

```
public class HealthChecker
{
    public bool status { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan totalDuration { get; set; }

    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }

    public HealthChecker()
    {
        entries = new List<Entry>();
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        TimeSpan time;
        string data;
        bool dbOk = TestDbs(out time, out data);

        var entry = new Entry
        {
            Type = "database",
            data = data,
            duration = time,
            status = dbOk
        };
        bool checkStatus = true;

        // Prepared in case of more entries (more controlls in one)
        foreach (var x in entries)
            checkStatus = checkStatus && x.status;

        this.status = checkStatus;
        this.entries.Add(entry);
        watch.Stop();
        time += watch.Elapsed;
        this.totalDuration = time;

    }

    private bool TestDbs(out TimeSpan time, out string exception)
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DriverDatabase))
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                watch.Stop();
                time = watch.Elapsed;
                exception = "";
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exception = e.ToString();
                watch.Stop();
                time = watch.Elapsed;
                return false;
            }
    }

    public JObject HealthStatus()
    {
        string stringFormat = "hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fffffff";
        var json = new JObject(
            new JProperty("status", this.status ? "Healthy" : "Degraded"),
            new JProperty("totalDuration", this.totalDuration.ToString(stringFormat)),
            new JProperty("entries", new JObject(
                new JProperty(this.entries.First().Type, 
                    new JObject(
                        new JProperty("data", 
                            new JObject(this.entries.First().data != null ? new JProperty("Error", this.entries.First().data) : null)),
                        new JProperty("duration", this.entries.First().duration.ToString(stringFormat)),
                        new JProperty("status", this.entries.First().status ? "Healthy" : "Degraded")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        return json;
    }
}
```

Entry.cs

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Type {get; set; }

    public string data { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan duration { get; set; }

    public bool status { get; set; }
}
```

And finally to webconfig I've added

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="20971520" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
<client/>
<services>
  <service name="DriverService.DriverService">
    <endpoint name="jsonEP"
              address="json"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="json"
              contract="DriverService.IDriverService"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DriverService.IDriverService"/>
  </service>
</services> 
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="256" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="json">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```